# How to fix http Error 500 in PDO execute statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to execute a query in php PDO but execute method causes HTTP ERROR 500

```
$query = "select * from job_t where title like '%:title%' and salary>=:salary";
$st = $conn->prepare($query);
$st->bindParam(":title", $_GET['title']);
$st->bindParam(":salary", $_GET['salary']);
$st->execute();
```

The expected output is table from job_t but the actual result is http error 500

Comment: Do not put the placeholder in quotes, it will treat it as a string. Add the wildcards to the variable you're binding, and only pass in the placeholder.  A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This  `'%:title%'` should not work .. so

try using concat  for build a proper  like  clause

```
$query = "select * from job_t 
  where title like concat('%', :title, '%')  and salary>=:salary";
```

Comment: In other words, `:x` type placeholders must be left bare. If it's inside a string then the driver goes out of its way to *not* substitute since it presumes you want to use literal `'%:title%'` as a string.